# Horizontally Center Image on Resize

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I'm stuck...

I have a slideshow with 1920px X 400px images. As is, the images only center when I'm at full-screen on a 1920px+ browser window. If I re-size my window, oh say, to 1600px, the images shift right of center and out of alignment with the rest of the site.

I want the slides to stay centered as I scale the width of my browser window and either show/hide the image area to the left and right based on the width of the browser. I DO NOT want to scale the image ratio and I can't use background images, either of which is an easy fix.

I'm assuming a JS listener that calculates the image width and the width of the browser window to continually display it in the center.

The demo site is here: http://bit.ly/YdMZDO

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on .slides-wrapper add these styles:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -960px; // half the width of your image block
```

Comment: Thanks man! I tried that at least five times on #slides and .slides-wrapper article... never on .slides-wrapper. I feel stupid.